# Vertical Align Not Taking Effect

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am not sure why my "Add to Favorites" text won't align to the middle of the blue element, which is what I would like it to do. I've added `vertical-align:middle` to both classes below. If I remove the fav.png picture inside the blue field the text just goes to the top of the red dotted box.

[image: Fav Box]

CSS:

```
.favouriteLink
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:3%;
    background-image: url('images/blueBanner.png');
    border-radius: 15px;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;

}

.favouriteLink a
{
    border: 1px dotted red;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="favouriteLink">
    <a href="javascript:alert('test')"><img class="navImg" src="images/fav.png" />Add to Favourites</a>
</div>
```

### EDIT:

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YcMgh/2/

For some reason setting the height as suggested to 40px would centre the text but only if the image was smaller which is why I didn't notice it originally. I'm a bit confused on this because how would changing the image position change the text? Is the text field not separate from the image?

For example...
Since my img is 32px by 32px this occurs- http://jsfiddle.net/YcMgh/3/

However if I change to 25px: http://jsfiddle.net/YcMgh/4/

Comment: `vertical-align` [only applies to inline elements and table cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height).

Comment: Align your image. See my for no reason downvoted answer.

Comment: What does the css for your `.navImg` look like?

Comment: The text is not separate from the image, because they share the same parent. By default, images get aligned to the baseline of adjacent text. You can see, that this is actually the case in your both example fiddles. But since the image is very large in your 32px example, in order to be still aligned to the baseline of the adjacent text, it pulls the text down. In your 25px example the image is small enough to fit between the top of the parent and the baseline of the text. If you reduce the size even further, you can see that the image starts getting some air to the top of it's parent `a`.

Comment: @Christoph Hey thanks that cleared a lot up. But why does the image push the dotted red element outside downward. Shouldn't it just grow until it meets the edge(dotted red border), rather than pushing the edge further down?

Comment: It won't. That's the disadvantage of defining a fixed pixel `line-height`. I can't tell you the exact reasons though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Add `line-height: 40px` to your `.favouriteLink a` rule.  I picked that since it matches the `height` you set for the button.
2. Add the rule `.favouriteLink img {vertical-align: middle;}`.  If that’s not quite where you want it, use length-based offsets like `vertical-align: -9px` or some such.

Answer (score 1):

Forget all the other answers. You just need to align your image properly. Its alignment to the baseline pushes the text down. Align it top or text-top to fix this.

[see Example-Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/YcMgh/1/)

You dont need vertical-align on the a or its container. You may need to [adjust the values](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/vertical-align) according to your imageheight/textheight.

Comment: I looked at your edit history.  I'm thinking maybe your original single-sentence answer was down-voted, _"You need to align your image properly."_

Comment: Personally, I have no problem with your recommended solution.  However, by your last sentence, you seem to ignore the fact that `vertical-align` [is not even applicable here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), where all this OP is using are block level elements.  Also, [your link](http://www.css4you.de/Texteigenschaften/vertical-align.html) is not in English.

Comment: Sry for the non-english link, but images are inline-elements and thus can/need to be aligned vertically.

Comment: My comment is not in reference to the `img`, but to this sentence, _"You dont need vertical-align on the a or its container."_  - It's not a matter of "need"... he just [cannot](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) use it on _"`a` or it's container"_, where he defined `a` as `display:block` and the container is a `div`.

Comment: I know very well, block-elements cant be aligned. I just wanted to point out that he tried to align on the “wrong level“ regardless of the display-type...

Comment: I found your jsfiddle helpful, if I expand the line height as mentioned from another user to 40px, then the text gets aligned to the middle. Interestingly if I remove any `verticle-align:middle` I still get the text to centre vertically - I have no idea how that's happening. (http://jsfiddle.net/PTq9S/). Also the alignment of the img doesn't really align in the middle by my eyes for some reason as well.

Comment: The whole Alignment is dependent to the dimensions of the line-, text- and imageheight. E.g. in your example using `text-bottom`works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this whole solution can be simplfied. Rather than including the image url for a button in your mark-up potentially a couple of times, I think it would be easier to move it into a CSS class. This way you can define a base CSS class that is a button without an image, and another class to add in the correct background image.

Other benefits of this approach is that background-images have alignment properties so that the image can easily be vertically aligned without much hassle.

An example of this mark-up would be as follows:

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('test');" class="link favourite-link">
    <span>Add to Favourites</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.link
{
    margin:5px;
    border:1px dashed #333;
    background:#ededed;
    border-radius: 15px;
    height:40px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:40px;
    padding:0 7px;
    width:250px;
}
.favourite-link span {
    background:url("image/goes/here.png") no-repeat left center;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:20px /* equal to icon width */;
}
```

**Note**: the extra `span` can be removed if you do not require the text to be central and the icon next to the text.

Comment: class="link favourite-link" does that call both classes "link" and "favourite-link"?

Comment: Yes,  you can have multiple classes on an element. It can be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this rule to .favouriteLink:

```
display:table-cell;
```

This will trigger your browser to align vertically in the manner you're probably expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I simply prefer using the `line-height: 40px; // Your height of your div` I like that because its easier to control how large an item's height is!

Comment: Indeed. Just be careful that your that your link's text doesn't wrap to more than one line.

Comment: for sure.  That is always the danger.  But as long as you have a set of predefined buttons, you should be ok.  err well predefined anything.  If its user generated content, be careful, because 40px line height will produce some funny effects :)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.favoriteLink * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

To get your desired results, you need to set `vertical-align` on all elements inside your `div`.

Comment: @Sparky672 The `a` doesn't need to be aligned; the `img` does. The `img` and the text are both inside the `a`. Using a selector like above is just easier in case you modify your markup later.

Comment: This will do nothing.  `vertical-align` is only applicable to inline elements with a specified height.  His are defined as block level.

Comment: Did you read the first line of the question?  _"I am not sure why my **"Add to Favorites" text won't align to the middle** of the blue element"_

Comment: Scroll down to `vertical-align` in [the W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) and explain how it could possibly apply to anything in this situation where **everything** here is defined as a block-level element.